# How to get length of dictionary value when sorted

Tags: python, dictionary

So i have this dictionary printed in console

```
source-document01321.txt
1 {'startPos': '216', 'endPos': '225'}
2 {'startPos': '3678', 'endPos': '3687'}
this is the length  2
source-document01323.txt
1 {'startPos': '2880', 'endPos': '2889'}
2 {'startPos': '6042', 'endPos': '6351'}
3 {'startPos': '14232', 'endPos': '14241'}
4 {'startPos': '16956', 'endPos': '16965'}
5 {'startPos': '22626', 'endPos': '22635'}
6 {'startPos': '24708', 'endPos': '24717'}
7 {'startPos': '34824', 'endPos': '34833'}
8 {'startPos': '36444', 'endPos': '36453'}
9 {'startPos': '38064', 'endPos': '38073'}
this is the length  9
source-document01259.txt
1 {'startPos': '3528', 'endPos': '3537'}
2 {'startPos': '10428', 'endPos': '10437'}
3 {'startPos': '12426', 'endPos': '12435'}
4 {'startPos': '18450', 'endPos': '18459'}
5 {'startPos': '24864', 'endPos': '24873'}
6 {'startPos': '27036', 'endPos': '27213'}
7 {'startPos': '30588', 'endPos': '31167'}
8 {'startPos': '34824', 'endPos': '34833'}
9 {'startPos': '44466', 'endPos': '44475'}
10 {'startPos': '45492', 'endPos': '45501'}
11 {'startPos': '46644', 'endPos': '46653'}
12 {'startPos': '51732', 'endPos': '51741'}
```

using this code

```
for key, value in doc_dict.iteritems():
    print key
    for k, v in value.iteritems():
        print k,v
    print "this is the length ", len(value)
```

i wanted to sort it based on the length of the value of each key in there in reverse order and get only the top 5 - which i have done using the code below

```
li = []
for k in sorted(doc_dict, key=lambda k: len(doc_dict[k]), reverse=True)[:5]:
    li.append(k)
pprint(li)
```

but that list contains only the keys

output:

```
['source-document01348.txt',
 'source-document01389.txt',
 'source-document01253.txt',
 'source-document01306.txt',
 'source-document01255.txt']
```

and i would also like to have the length of the value next to each key, so i can calculate percentages after that

i.e

```
[
 ['source-document01348.txt', '40'],
 ['source-document01389.txt', '35']
]
```

what change do i need to make , to make that happen?

Comment: I am curious if my code works. Would you pls test it and give me feedback? thx

Comment: Hey @sparkandshine will let you know in a while thanks

Comment: u might forget to test my code. I am waiting for ur response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for k in sorted(doc_dict, key=lambda k: len(doc_dict[k]), reverse=True)[:5]:
    li.append((k,len(doc_dict[k])))
```

Just do the calculation again, appending a tuple `(key, len(value))`

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Change `li.append(k)` to:

`li.append([k,len(doc_dict[k])])`

Answer (score 0):

Use `sorted(doc_dict.items(), ...`，

```
for k, v in sorted(doc_dict.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[0]), reverse=True)[:5]:
    li.append([k, len(v)])
```